# How to resolve java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: android, unknown-host

I was taken internet permission in manifest file. My mobile network connection is also working.
The main code:

```
/**
 * Created by Yogesh on 5/07/2016.
 */
public class All_Item_Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {
    // Declare Variables
    JSONArray jsonarray = null;
    ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemlist;
    static String NAME = "name";
    static String DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    static String PRICE = "price";
    static String IMAGE = "image_path";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_item_layout, container, false);
        itemlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new ReadJSON().execute();
        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        return view;
    }

    private class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            itemlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            JSONObject jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://mahatiffin.com/web/selectallmenu.php");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("AllMenu");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    map.put("Description", jsonobject.getString("Description"));
                    map.put("price", jsonobject.getString("price"));
                    map.put("image_path", jsonobject.getString("image_path"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    itemlist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), itemlist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            list.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
        }
    }
}


public class JSONfunctions {
    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

In may fragment page nothing is showing only blank page will be displayed.

The log output:

```
>05-18 17:43:11.730 27019-27019/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
    05-18 17:43:11.740 27019-27082/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin E/log_tag: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-18 17:43:11.740 27019-27082/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin E/log_tag: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    05-18 17:43:11.770 27019-27082/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin W/dalvikvm: threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e11378)
    05-18 17:43:11.770 27019-27082/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTas...(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin.All_Item_Fragment$ReadJSON.doInBackground(All_Item_Fragment.java:58)
    at com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin.All_Item_Fragment$ReadJSON.doInBackground(All_Item_Fragment.java:43)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTas...(FutureTask.java:137) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
    05-18 17:43:12.420 27019-27019/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for Veg_Item_Fragment{415d7030 #1 id=0x7f0c00a0 android:switcher:2131493024:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
    05-18 17:43:12.530 27019-27104/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin E/log_tag: Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "mahatiffin.com": No address associated with hostname
    05-18 17:43:12.540 27019-27104/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin E/log_tag: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-18 17:43:12.540 27019-27104/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin E/log_tag: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    05-18 17:43:12.570 27019-27104/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin W/dalvikvm: threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e11378)
    05-18 17:43:12.570 27019-27104/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27019 SIG: 9
```

How do I fix                                                                                       this?

Comment: Post your code as well!

Comment: remove the connection successful string from response

Comment: "connection successful" remove from JSON form http://mahatiffin.com/web/selectallmenu.php and run the program.

Comment: <?php

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "mahatiff_user";
$password = "vashi@123";
$database = "mahatiff_db";

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if ($connect) {
   echo "connection successful" . "<br>";
} else {
    echo "not connected";
}

?>

Answer (score 15):

**Reason**: Usually the UnknownHostException fires when you cannot resolve the DNS record of the URL you've provided. There's a reasonable timeout for that operation, but if you have a weak Wi-Fi connection or you          don't have enough signal on your device, the communication can be interrupted in the middle between sending a request and receiving a response, so your device doesn't receive a response, thus it thinks it's a DNS timeout.

Long story short, there are two main reasons for exception:

1. If your Wi-Fi signals is weak.
2. If your device connected to the Wi-Fi but no internet is not available.

**Solution**: Before request check availability of internet

```
public static boolean isInternetOn(Context context) {

    if (isMobileOrWifiConnectivityAvailable(context)) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            urlc.connect();
            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          DebugLog.console("Couldn't check internet connection Exception is : " + e);
        }
    } else {
        DebugLog.console("Internet not available!");
    }
    return false;
}


public static boolean isMobileOrWifiConnectivityAvailable(Context ctx) {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;


    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected()) {
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
                }
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected()) {
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        DebugLog.console("[ConnectionVerifier] inside isInternetOn() Exception is : " + e.toString());
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Comment: @joe jeff, Best explanation I've seen after researching for 2 hours about UnknownHostException.

Comment: @joe jeff, but, I think, checking connection before the request does not saves you from connection getting weak between sending a request and receiving a response or while receiving a response. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

```
  connection successful
    {
    "AllMenu": [{
        "0": "3",
        "menu_id": "3",
        "1": "Aloo Parathas",
        "name": "Aloo Parathas",
        "2": "170",
        "price": "170",
        "3": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "Description": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/1.jpg",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/1.jpg",
        "5": "Regular-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Regular-menu",
        "6": "1",
        "type_id": "1"
    }, {
        "0": "7",
        "menu_id": "7",
        "1": "ZzaxZxszsc",
        "name": "ZzaxZxszsc",
        "2": "343",
        "price": "343",
        "3": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "Description": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/2.jpg",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/2.jpg",
        "5": "Regular-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Regular-menu",
        "6": "1",
        "type_id": "1"
    }, {
        "0": "8",
        "menu_id": "8",
        "1": "sdcsdvsd",
        "name": "sdcsdvsd",
        "2": "435",
        "price": "435",
        "3": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "Description": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/3.jpg",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/3.jpg",
        "5": "Special-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Special-menu",
        "6": "2",
        "type_id": "2"
    }, {
        "0": "9",
        "menu_id": "9",
        "1": "sadcasc",
        "name": "sadcasc",
        "2": "435",
        "price": "435",
        "3": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "Description": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/4.jpg",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/4.jpg",
        "5": "Regular-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Regular-menu",
        "6": "2",
        "type_id": "2"
    }, {
        "0": "10",
        "menu_id": "10",
        "1": "sadcasc",
        "name": "sadcasc",
        "2": "456",
        "price": "456",
        "3": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "Description": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/5.jpg",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/5.jpg",
        "5": "Regular-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Regular-menu",
        "6": "1",
        "type_id": "1"
    }, {
        "0": "11",
        "menu_id": "11",
        "1": "sda",
        "name": "sda",
        "2": "234",
        "price": "234",
        "3": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "Description": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/6.JPG",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/6.JPG",
        "5": "Special-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Special-menu",
        "6": "2",
        "type_id": "2"
    }, {
        "0": "12",
        "menu_id": "12",
        "1": "sadcasc",
        "name": "sadcasc",
        "2": "324",
        "price": "324",
        "3": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "Description": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/7.JPEG",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/7.JPEG",
        "5": "Regular-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Regular-menu",
        "6": "1",
        "type_id": "1"
    }, {
        "0": "14",
        "menu_id": "14",
        "1": "sadcasc",
        "name": "sadcasc",
        "2": "232",
        "price": "232",
        "3": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "Description": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/1.jpg",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/1.jpg",
        "5": "Special-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Special-menu",
        "6": "1",
        "type_id": "1"
    }, {
        "0": "15",
        "menu_id": "15",
        "1": "sadcasc",
        "name": "sadcasc",
        "2": "325",
        "price": "325",
        "3": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "Description": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/2.jpg",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/2.jpg",
        "5": "Special-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Special-menu",
        "6": "2",
        "type_id": "2"
    }, {
        "0": "16",
        "menu_id": "16",
        "1": "sadcasc",
        "name": "sadcasc",
        "2": "344",
        "price": "344",
        "3": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "Description": "fjhsjfh jfhrwkjfh wejfhwkh ewjfhwjeh ewjfhkwe ewbfjeh wejhfkjwhhef ehfkwh wewjrh",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/4.jpg",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/4.jpg",
        "5": "Regular-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Regular-menu",
        "6": "1",
        "type_id": "1"
    }, {
        "0": "18",
        "menu_id": "18",
        "1": "edfwdfewr",
        "name": "edfwdfewr",
        "2": "23",
        "price": "23",
        "3": "xasx scasc dqedqd edbhwd dwh3ej1 1wh1e2ue 3eh3ue e2euh23ueej ewnwencj",
        "Description": "xasx scasc dqedqd edbhwd dwh3ej1 1wh1e2ue 3eh3ue e2euh23ueej ewnwencj",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/4.jpg",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/4.jpg",
        "5": "Regular-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Regular-menu",
        "6": "2",
        "type_id": "2"
    }, {
        "0": "19",
        "menu_id": "19",
        "1": "Aloo Gobi",
        "name": "Aloo Gobi",
        "2": "250",
        "price": "250",
        "3": "Aloo Sabzi, 2 Puris, Rice, Dal, Shrikhand",
        "Description": "Aloo Sabzi, 2 Puris, Rice, Dal, Shrikhand",
        "4": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/1.jpg",
        "image_path": "http:\/\/mahatiffin.com\/uploads\/1.jpg",
        "5": "Special-menu",
        "menu_cat": "Special-menu",
        "6": "1",
        "type_id": "1"
    }]
}
```

Remove String "connection successful" from Php Json at start of the page.

2) Problem Class cast exception: change as bellow :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_item_layout, container, false);
        itemlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new ReadJSON().execute();
        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), itemlist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
        return view;
    }
```

and

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
          adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
        }
```

and

remove " itemlist = new ArrayList>(); " from `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: sir i will remove that after removing my logcat show me error like this--java.lang.ClassCastException: com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin.ListViewAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ListAdapter

Comment: after override adapter.notifydatasetchanged(); it says create method notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: See the custom Adapter listview Eaxmple :https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html  You need to extends Base Adapter

Comment: image cannot be load into listview the error is like this-- java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "mahatiffin.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: and another error is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard1/MahaTiffinCache/1027196006: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: i will copy my code this link http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/ now error is image cant be fetch from server into my listview only default image it shows

Comment: i will take write_external_storage permission into manifest file after that error was gone..thnxx sir thanku so much..:)

Comment: i wan take data from server into my edittext while i m type into edittext related possibilities are comes into edittext and it fill automatically

Comment: here i will post this with code-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344099/how-to-fetch-data-from-server-into-edittext