# Why is UnknownHostException thrown on Android 9 while connecting to reachable host?

Tags: java, android, mqtt

I have an app that uses MQTT `org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5` to connect through SSL (with SHA256 certificate as required by newest Android versions) and it works fine on Android 7 but same app throws `UnknownHostException` exception on Android 9. My `compileSdkVersion` is 30.

Here is a stack trace:

```
2020-12-07 09:48:37.124 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err: MqttException (0) - java.net.UnknownHostException: bialystok.pl
2020-12-07 09:48:37.124 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
2020-12-07 09:48:37.125 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:738)
2020-12-07 09:48:37.125 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
2020-12-07 09:48:37.126 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bialystok.pl
2020-12-07 09:48:37.126 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:209)
2020-12-07 09:48:37.126 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
2020-12-07 09:48:37.127 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
2020-12-07 09:48:37.127 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptSocketBase.connect(ConscryptSocketBase.java:152)
2020-12-07 09:48:37.127 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:74)
2020-12-07 09:48:37.128 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:132)
2020-12-07 09:48:37.128 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:724)
2020-12-07 09:48:37.128 21211-21351/pl.app.my W/System.err:     ... 1 more
```

What may be the reason?

Comment: Restart the emulator

Comment: do you have [network-security-config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#manifest) set up?

Comment: Can you check if your internet works :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314712/how-to-resolve-java-net-unknownhostexception

Comment: @aran not on emulator, on real device

Comment: check if android has internet access permissions then

Comment: What network was the device connected to when it failed? Does it work if you say turn off WiFi (or vice versa e.g. use cellular connection rather than WiFi)?